# Problem populating input values in a form after fetching from the backend

Tags: jquery, ajax

Am working on a form whereby after the user hits submit button, am submitting the data to the backend using AJAX whereby I fetch some more values and redirect back to the frontend using AJAX. I want to **fetch the values via Jquery and populate them in the form**. Next populate the values back to the form **since I dont want to submit the form via AJAX since it si supposed to open an iframe**.

**Form Layout**

```
 <form id="eazzycheckout-payment-form" action="https://*****************************checkout/launch" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="custName" id="custName" value="{{ $first }} {{ $last }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="{{ $token}}">
        <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="{{ $grossPre }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="orderReference" name="orderReference" value="{{ $quoteRef }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="orderID" name="orderID" value="{{ $quoteRef }}">
        <input type="hidden" id="merchantCode" name="merchantCode" value="*

**********">
        <input type="hidden" id="merchant" name="merchant" value="**********">
        <input type="hidden" id="outletCode" name="outletCode" value="0000000000">

        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top payment" src="{{asset('assets/images-new/mastercard.svg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title payment">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit-cg" value="Checkout" style="cursor: pointer;" class="jenga"> Make Payment </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Hidden form-->
    </form>
```

**AJAX to fetch the values from the response of backend and populate the form**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'jengaAPI',
    data: JSON.stringify(type),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        //Fetch from response and populate the form values
        var amount = $('#amount').val(response.amount);
        var orderReference = $('#orderReference').val(response.payment_reference);
        var orderID = $('#orderID').val(response.payment_reference);
        //End fetch
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        //alert('Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is your exact problem with this?

Comment: I want to populate the values I get from the response back to the form

Comment: Dont want to submit the form via AJAX since am suppposed to load an iframe after the form action

Comment: If you use ajax post, please change button type submit -> type button.
<button type="button" ..

Comment: @sonpham Am getting the response fine,, I just want to store the values in a variable populate it back to the form input fields and send the form

Comment: is your form is loading after submitting a form?

Comment: @NegiRox My form is hidden and after I get the response via AJAX I want to populate some input fields in the form and submit the form posssibly via Jquery,,,, but am not sure how to handle this

Comment: when your are clicking on "Make payment" button is your page refreshed?

Comment: @NegiRox No,, Am submitting the form asynchronously,, but I want to fetch the values from the repose and populate them in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change this line

```
  <button type="submit" id="submit-cg" value="Checkout" style="cursor: pointer;" class="jenga"> Make Payment </button>

  <input type="button" id="submit-cg" value="Checkout" style="cursor: pointer;" class="jenga"> Make Payment </button>
```

when you are using button type"submit" it will refresh the page and set the html control in its default value.